# Change the default version of MSSqlLocalDB for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, c#, sql-server-2016

I am working on a C# project with SQL Server. For development, we use **LocalDB** instance of SQL Server. If something is changed in the database, we check-in the `.mdf`/`.ldf` files into TFS. The connection is made using `MSSqlLocalDB`.

**The problem**

After upgrades on some systems, we are now using VS 2013 and VS 2015, both for development. The issue started because of the fact that **VS 2013 defaults to SQL Server 2014** and **VS 2015 defaults to SQL Server 2016** for LocalDB instances.

Once the `.MDF` file has been opened with 2016, it becomes incompatible with 2014. Due to this, people using 2015 can't check-in the database changes.

To solve it, I installed Version 2014 of LocalDB on to machines with VS 2015 but unable to change the default version to which VS connects to.

CAN ANYONE HELP ME??

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me 2 days to find the solution to this problem.

Posting here for anybody who faces the issue in future.

I basically removed all instances of `LocalDB` from my system and reinstalled them.
Following are the steps that were required to finally solve the issue

1. Remove all the databases attached to the `LocalDB 2016`
2. Remove `LocalDB 2016`
3. Remove `LocalDB 2014`
4. Restart the system
5. Reinstall `LocalDB 2014`

For installation of `LocalDB 2014`, either use the standalone file from "https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42299" OR
Select **Express** from standard Sql Server Setup and then select `LocalDB` in the component list

Comment: How did you remove them?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I found the entries in the."Programs and Features" and I simply double click on the option to Uninstall

Comment: Thanks Bimal, I had a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51164180/sql-server-express-connection-to-mdf-file